# Functions and return const char*

Tags: arrays, c++-cli, char, constants

```
const char* test(bool i)
{
    const char t[] = "aa\n";
    const char* p = "bbb\n";
    if(i)
        return p;
    return t;
}
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
     printf(test(true));
     printf(test(false));
     return 0;
}
```

That returns something of sort:

```
 bbb
 %^&$^$%
```

It is clear that **test(false)** returns a pointer to a local variable. The question is that p is also local variable. Why the memory for "bbb\n" is not cleaned after the function returns. I thought const char[] is interpreted same way as const char* but it is not true as it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p` is a local variable, which you return by value, but points to a **string literal**, which resides in read-only memory, not in the automatic memory allocated for the method.

Returning `t` and the using it indeed results in undefined behavior.

Also, don't think of pointers and arrays to be equivalent.

Comment: does the standard dictates the way string literal are stored? I.e., the fact that the string is (in common experience) in a read-only memory that will exist until the end of the whole program, is this a standard mandatory behaviour? If it is not, it could exist a compiler that put the string literal in the stack of the function... why not (if the standard does not dictate anything about)

Comment: @ShinTakezou: Section 3.7.1: "All variables which do not have dynamic storage duration, do not have thread storage duration, and are not local have static storage duration.  The storage for these entities shall last for the duration of the program."

Comment: @BenVoigt thanks. Even if to be "exact" string literals are not variables, so this section couldn't apply to them. But I suppose this is a "nuance", and that section refers to string literals (too).

Comment: @ShinTakezou: Footnote 170, on page 433, also explicitly claims that string literals are static.

Comment: @BenVoigt thanks again. This is a stronger "evidence". (Just to be sure, are we talking about the C++ standard, right?)

Comment: @ShinTakezou: Yes.  I'm referring to draft n3290, but I believe it's word-for-word identical to the approved standard in almost every section.

Answer (score 6):

Although `p` is a local variable, what it points to is not local - it is a compile-time string constant; it is legal to return that constant's address from a function.

`t` is different, because the compile-time string constant is *copied* into an automatic storage area, causing an undefined behavior on dereferencing the returned pointer.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it isn't returning the pointer that causes undefined behavior, but dereferencing it later.

Comment: @BenVoigt You are absolutely right, I edited the answer to clarify this point.