# Return a const char *

Tags: c++, function, char, constants

I wrote a function which returns the current date. Inside the function, I  "cout" the result and it work but when I "cout" the function, it does not work. I got garbage.

```
const char* engineCS::getDate() const
{
    time_t t = time(0);
    struct tm *now = localtime(&t);
    char buf[20];
    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y-%m-%d %X", now);
    cout << buf << endl;
    return buf;
}
```

Exemple :
Inside : 2012-02-02 00:00:00
Outside : ?????fv

What is wrong?
Similar problem : [Functions and return const char*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668923/functions-and-return-const-char)

THX

Edit: 
What is wrong now? Sorry I've done too much VB.NET...

```
const char* engineCS::getDate() const
{
    time_t t = time(0);
    struct tm *now = localtime(&t);
    char *buf;
    buf = new char[20];
    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y-%m-%d %X", now);
    cout << buf << endl;
    return buf;
}
```

Comment: You're returning a pointer to a local. Don't do that.

Comment: The SO question you link to ... answers your question. You can't return a pointer to something on the stack.

Comment: use `malloc` or `new`, buff is temporary. Generally It crashes, you got garbage. its UB

Comment: I wonder why to use `char *` when there is `std::string` in C++?

Comment: Just to learn the old good way ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your function to return `std::string`, and everything will be fine. You won't need to make any further changes apart from the return type. If the consumer needs a raw `char const *`, call the `c_str()` member function on the resulting string.

Comment: @Naster: I can't force your mind, but if you ask me, you should rather learn C++!

Comment: @Naster Instead of "char *buf;" and
    "buf = new char[20];"
try: "static char buf[20];"   or for your first example code, just put a "static" in front of "char buf[20];"